# Unable to write new lines to File

Tags: java, android, arraylist, filereader, filewriter

I have a bunch of strings that I'm writing to a file:

```
private void writeScoreToFile(BlastScore result)
    {
        try{
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(getFilesDir() + CaptureActivity.BLAST_SCORES,true);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write(Integer.toString(result.getBlastScore()));
            out.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Write Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I would like to read it back in as a List.

```
private List<String> getArrayFromFile(String filename) throws IOException
    {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(getFilesDir() + filename);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return lines;
    }
```

The list that is being written is:

```
100
96
100
96
100
```

When I print the List it looks like

```
10-28 21:22:31.130: I/System.out(936): Last Score: 1009610096100
```

Here is the code I am using to print it:

```
try {
            List<String> blastScores = getArrayFromFile(CaptureActivity.BLAST_SCORES);
            System.out.println("Last Score: " + blastScores.get(blastScores.size()-1));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Read Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

I'm trying to get the n-1 element.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing the Integers or Integer Strings you are not putting a new line character after each output. Hence, your file has only one line of data, which line you are getting as a continuous String...
To fix, add a line separator like write.newLine() in between separate write() calls.

Answer (score 0):

The code which writes the scores uses

```
out.write(Integer.toString(result.getBlastScore()));
```

This means that if the method is called with scores 12, 100 and 2, your file will look like

```
121002
```

since you don't write any separator. How do you want to parse this into three numbers correctly?

Use a `PrintWriter` that wraps the `BufferedWriter`, and use its `println` method to write the score.

Note that writing the scores one by one by opening the file and closing it each time won't be very fast. BTW, using a BufferedWriter just to write a single integer won't gain any benefit. You also have bad exception handling : the streams and readers/writers should always be closed in a finally block.

Answer (score 0):

In your `writeScoreToFile` function I don't see any new line or any sort of delimiter that would separate each score being written.

In that case your file would in fact contain `1009610096100` on a single line and the loop inside `getArrayFromFile` would only be executed once:

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
   lines.add(line);
}
```

Therefore your `List<String>` only contains 1 element and the code `blastScores.get(blastScores.size()-1)` will get the last and **only** element, that obviously being `1009610096100`.